# Use Rails credentials encryption to encrypt files

Tags: credentials, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to use Rails credentials encryption in the code.

I want to encrypt the file by passing the file with credentials and encryption key to the
method.
I want the result to be a usable encrypted credentials file.

Not sure if i can use credentials encryption in Ruby code as i would like to and i don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Given `_PATH_/file_to_be_encrypted.txt` as the file to encrypt:

```
encrypted = Rails.application.encrypted('_PATH_/file_to_be_encrypted.txt.enc')
encrypted.write(File.read('_PATH_/file_to_be_encrypted.txt'))
```

To read encrypted file:

```
Rails.application.encrypted('_PATH_/file_to_be_encrypted.txt.enc').read
```